# why php mysqli does not insert data to database in Xampp

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, xampp

i used the following code to insret data to a database called sample, the table is also called sample.. their are four fields first_name, last_name, bio, created. 
When I

but when I use this code while has an html form to input the data..It does not work. I do not get any error messages back...the data is not inserted into the database..

[code]

```
   <?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //require 'functions/security.php';
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sample');

    //check connection
    if($db->connect_errno) {
        die('sorry, we are having some problems');
        }else {
        echo 'connected';
    }

    $records = array();

    if(!empty($_POST)) {
      if(isset($_POST['first_name'], $_POST['lats_name'],$_POST['bio'])){

            $first_name  = trim($_POST['first_name']);
            $last_name   = trim($_POST['last_name']);
            $bio         = mtrim($_POST['bio']);

            if(!empty($first_name) && !empty($last_name) && !empty($bio) ){

            $insert = $db->prepare
            ("INSERT INTO sample(first_name, last_name, bio, created) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, NOW())");
            $insert->bind_param('sss',$first_name, $last_name, $bio);

            if($insert->execute()){
                header('Location: index.php');
                die();
                }

            }
        }
      } 

    if($results = $db->query("Select * from sample")) {
        if($results->num_rows){
            while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
                $records[] = $row;
            }
            $results->free();
        }
    }


    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

        <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Sample</h3>
            <?php
            if(!count($records)) {
            echo 'No records';

            } else {

            ?>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>first name</th>
                        <th>Last name</th>
                        <th>Bio</th>
                        <th>Created</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach($records as $r){
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r->first_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r->last_name; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r->bio ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r->created; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }

                        ?>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <hr>
            <form action=""method="POST">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="first_name">first_name"</label>
                    <input type ="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="last_name">last_name" </label>
                    <input type ="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="bio">bio" </label>
                    <textarea name="bio" id="bio"></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="insert">
                </div>
            </form>

            </hr>

        </body>
    </html>


[/code]
```

Comment: You're not checking for errors. That's why you don't see any.

Comment: Because `name="last_name"` + `$_POST['lats_name']` = no love.

Comment: Also `mtrim($_POST['bio'])` there is no `mtrim` PHP function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `name="last_name"` + `$_POST['lats_name']` typo-mismatch.

It should be `$_POST['last_name']`

Also `mtrim($_POST['bio'])` there is no `mtrim` PHP core function.

- **http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mtrim&scope=quickref**

Do as you did for the other two:

```
$first_name  = trim($_POST['first_name']);
$last_name   = trim($_POST['last_name']);
$bio         = trim($_POST['bio']);
```

Using error reporting in your file(s) will help during production testing, and should have signaled that error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

which you are apparently using something similar, but wanted to drop that in there.

---

Sidenote: Consider spacing this out a bit `<form action=""method="POST">`

`<form action="" method="POST">`

Comment: Thanks everyone I made those corrections. I don't get any error codes. but data still does not insret into database...

Comment: I'm able to insert data to the database when I run this [code]if($insert = $db->query("
INSERT INTO sample(first_name, last_name, bio, created) 
 VALUES ('testJane', 'lasttestname', 'test record', NOW())")){
 echo $db->affected_rows;
 } [/code]

Comment: No it is not working.. It still does not insert the data to the database

Comment: I noticed both your DB `('localhost', 'root', '', 'sample')` and table `INSERT INTO sample` are named the same "`sample`". Are you sure you didn't make a mistake with those? Check your column names also and their types including the (max/min) length. @Darius If the lengths are too small to accomodate the data, it will fail.

Comment: I did it on purpose to keep things simple..I created this code tofigure out why the code i'm actually wanting to produce does not work..this is a simpler form and code. if I can get this to work..then I may be able to figure out why the other one does not work...

Comment: Would the collation make a difference?

Comment: @Darius I don't think so. Give me a few minutes, I'll test your entire code. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Darius I tested your code and was successful. All my columns were of `VARCHAR(255)` and the `created` column set to `DATETIME`, so I don't know why it is not working for you. Make sure you're also not trying to insert the same record if your column(s) is set to UNIQUE.

Comment: @Darius You are filling in all the fields in the form, right? If not, it will not insert anything, even if there is one not filled. As I said, I tested what you posted in your question along with my fixed answer and it worked.

Comment: I fixed the problem. I used the following to do so. I posted echos through out the code to see what was going on. and I used the following to see error codes.                                          error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1'); but i also included the PHP code on the same page as the HTML. I couldn't get it to work when I tried to make the form call the ver.php document..